# How can I unchecked default Save in address book checkbox checkout shipping address popup?

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout

How can I show unchecked Save in address book at checkout when adding new shipping address?

Please suggest me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which onestepcheckout you are using. But you can check in core checkout how it works refer below files

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.html

```
    <!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn) -->
    <div class="field choice" data-bind="visible: !isFormInline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="shipping-save-in-address-book" data-bind="checked: saveInAddressBook" />
        <label class="label" for="shipping-save-in-address-book">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Save in address book'"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

In above code the checkbox value is bind `data-bind="checked: saveInAddressBook" />` This value is set in shipping.js file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
    isNewAddressAdded: ko.observable(false),
    saveInAddressBook: 1, //Change this value to 0
```

Redeploy your static content

clear cache and check